# Difference between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

What are the basic differences between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$?

The points in these two sets are written as ordered pairs, I mean the structure looks similar to me. So what is the reason to denote these two sets differently?

Comment: If you are familiar with the language of abstract algebra, $\mathbb{C}\cong \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: That MUST be a duplicate.

Comment: As sets, they are identical. As groups, vector spaces, also. The point is that we denote and use $\mathbb{C}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^2$ when we need or refer to its field structure.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on what you mean by $\mathbf{R}^2$. You can write $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$, but the "$\times$" can have several different meanings depending on which *category* you are working in.

**As sets:**

If you view $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ as sets, this means you are ignoring any possible structure on these things besides their elements (so forget about multiplication, addition, anything.) From this perspective, $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are the same object (in technical terms they are isomorphic in the category of sets) because there is a bijection
$$(a,b)\ \leftrightarrow\ a+bi.$$
A key thing to note about this is that "$\times$" refers to a direct product of sets, i.e. the Cartesian product. This will change as we add more structure.

**As real vector spaces:**

You can give each of $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ the structure of a real vector space, meaning you can add vectors and multiply by real numbers. Then from the theory of linear algebra, we know that $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ has a basis of $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ has a (real) basis of $\{1, i\}$. Since these real vector spaces both have dimension 2, they are isomorphic (in the linear algebra sense, i.e. in the category of $\mathbf{R}$-modules). So from this perspective they are again the same object.

Note here that $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ can be interpreted as $\mathbf{R}\oplus \mathbf{R}$ which may be more familiar to linear algebra students. The point is that now we are requiring more from the operation (it has to preserve addition of vectors now).

**As rings:**

Here is where the difference comes in. We can think of $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ as *rings*, meaning we can add and multiply elements together according to some axioms. Then if you write $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$, you mean a direct product *in the category of rings*, so now multiplication in $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ has to satisfy
$$(a,b)\cdot (c,d)=(ac,bd).$$
But in particular this means things like
$$(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0),$$
which means it is possible for two nonzero things to have a product zero. In contrast, if $z_1z_2=0$ in $\mathbf{C}$, then either $z_1=0$ or $z_2=0$. In this way, $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ have *fundamentally different* behavior as rings. Because of this, there is no isomorphism of rings between the two objects.

**As fields:**

A field is a commutative ring with more structure (we can invert multiplication for nonzero things). It turns out that $\mathbf{C}$ can be given the structure of a field because $z^{-1}$ exists for any nonzero $z\in\mathbf{C}$, but $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ cannot be a field because equations like $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=(0,0)$ mess everything up (try to cancel something from the left side).

---

> tl;dr -- You have to specify what you mean by "$\times$". $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$ are exactly the same until you start saying you want to do things like multiply elements together.

Comment: That means the main difference is that , $\mathbb C$ is an integral domain but  $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: is there any difference between  $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \times....\times\mathbb R$ (n times)

Comment: @analysis89 Right, and because all fields are integral domains, this means it's impossible for something not an integral domain to be a field. $\mathbf{R}^n$ is just shorthand for $\mathbf{R}\times\cdots\times\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: @Germain that is its definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_product

Answer (score 13):

Well $\mathbb{R}^2$ is (by default) interpreted as a vectorspace. So normally you only expect addition and scalar multiplication in it. Which give different algebraic structures.

And I want to add something. The points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are written normally as tupels, namely $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $ x=(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$. 
The elements of $\mathbb{C}$ have (at least) 3 common ways to denote. 
\begin{align*}
z&=a+i\cdot b \quad a,b\in \mathbb{R}\\
z&=(a,b)\\
z&=|z|\cdot \exp(i\varphi)
\end{align*}
The first and the second look pretty much the same, but in $\mathbb{C}$ the multiplication is a function
$$ \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$$
while the scalar multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a function
$$ \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$$
You can copy the structure of $\mathbb{C}$ and put it on $\mathbb{R}^2$, to make it a field for example.

But for example the differentiability is different in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and in $\mathbb{C}$ namely a function which is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ need to fulfill the Cauchy Riemann differential equations to be complex differentiable.

Comment: To say it in an easy english, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are like twins, even though they are not the same they look pretty much the same

Answer (score 8):

$\Bbb C$ is a field in its own right with an operation of multiplication.  $\Bbb R^2$ does not have that.

Answer (score 5):

To put it succinctly, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a vector space while $\mathbb{C}$ is a field. One of the first difference to be noticed is that you can divide two complex numbers but you cannot divide two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Some would argue that every field is a vector space over itself.

Comment: Yep every field is a VS over itself but every VS certainly isn't a field. So that's a (big) difference between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$. $\mathbb{C}$ is both but $\mathbb{R}^2$ is *only* a VS.

Answer (score 3):

If we desire that every integer has an inverse element, we have to invent rational numbers and many things become much simpler.
If we desire every polynomial equation to have a root, we have to extend the real number field $\mathbb{R}$ to a larger field $\mathbb{C}$ of 'complex numbers', and many statements become more homogeneous. To construct a complex number, we associate with each real number $a$ second real number $b$.
A complex number is then an ordered pair of real numbers (a,b).
We write that new number as $a+bi$.

Complex numbers contain solutions to all polynomial equations and hence are an algebraically closed field unlike the real numbers. The complex numbers are not an ordered field. $\mathbb{C}$ is geometrically represented by identifying it with $\mathbb{R^2}$. (This is sometimes called the
Argand diagram).