# Using the fifth root of unity to show the cosine equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Consider the equation expressed the fifth root of unity: $z^5-1=0$

To show that: $$2(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})+\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5}))=-1\\4\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5})=-1$$

I have already shown the first one by using the sum of the root is zero and the truth that $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})=\cos(\frac{8\pi}{5})$ and $\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5})=\cos(\frac{6\pi}{5})$.

Now I am stacking on the second one and totally have no idea about how to do it.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660361/how-do-i-interpret-eulers-formula. and   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480102/quadratic-substitution-question-applying-substitution-p-x-frac1x-to-2x4x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The sum of the five roots is zero because $z^5-1$ has no fourth-degree term. What does the fact that there is no third-degree term tell you?

Comment: Thanks, I got that.