# Complex numbers and conjugates.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given that $|z|=√3$, solve the equation $$2\overline{z}+\frac3{iz}=\sqrt{15}.$$

How to solve this question **without** a calculator?

Comment: Could you edit your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)? It's unclear what you're asking and where the division symbol should be.

Comment: @Vittal Kamath, so what is the answer did you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Multiplying by $z$ we obtain

$$2\bar z+\frac3{iz}=\sqrt{15} \implies 2\bar zz+\frac3{iz}z\frac i i=\sqrt{15}z$$

then recall that $\bar z z=|z|^2$.

Comment: ,what are the next steps to arrive at final answer?

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod What did you obtain from here $2\bar zz+\frac3{iz}z\frac i i=\sqrt{15}z$?

Comment: ,I got $6+ \frac{3}{i}=\sqrt{45}$

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod Why that? We have $\bar z z=|z|^2$ and here we are ok, then $\frac 3 i =-3i$ but at the RHS we should have $\sqrt{15}z$.

Comment: because|z|=$\sqrt{3}$. If this is wrong,then $z=\frac{6-3i}{\sqrt{15}}$

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod Exactly, we can obtain z form that. And you can check that |z| is indeed $\sqrt 3$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $z=\sqrt3e^{it}\implies\bar z=\sqrt3e^{-it}$ where $t$ is real

$$\sqrt{15}=2\sqrt3e^{-it}+\dfrac3{i\sqrt3e^{it}}=\sqrt3(2-i)e^{-it}$$

$$\iff e^{it}=\dfrac{2-i}{\sqrt5}$$

We are done.

We can go even further.

$$e^{it}=e^{-i\arcsin\dfrac1{\sqrt5}}$$

$$\implies t=2n\pi -\arcsin\dfrac1{\sqrt5}$$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: ,what is WLOG z means?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Without_loss_of_generality

Comment: I know $e^{i\pi}=-1$. So what is $e^{it}?$ and why did you multiply it by z?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660361/how-do-i-interpret-eulers-formula