# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ a Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

From what I know, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a group under addition, defined as $(a, b) + (c, d) = (a+b,c+d)$. However, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364164/793776) answer on another question seems to suggest that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is actually a ring with multiplication defined as $(a, b)\cdot (c, d) = (ac, bd)$. I thought that we usually only define multiplication over the group $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $(a, b)\cdot (c,d) = (ac - bd, ad+bc)$, and in result end up making it a field called $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You can put multiple different algebraic structures on the same set.  That's why a group/ring is a set together with specified operations, not just a set by itself.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ not an algebraic structure -- a group? @Randall

Comment: As you described it, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a ring:  commutative, with identity, but not a field nor integral domain.

Comment: @ICanKindOfCode $\Bbb R^2$ does have a "default" additive structure, so it is indeed typically considered a group. However, it does not have a "default" multiplicative structure, so it is not usually considered a ring.

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: @Randall so if it's a ring, then it does have a default multiplicative structure?

Comment: There is no default. That's the whole point.

Comment: Then what exactly is $\mathbb{R}^2$ if it does not have a default multiplicative structure defined? It should be a group and not a ring, right?

Comment: It is just the set of all ordered pairs (until you clarify in your **writing** what you want the symbol to mean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the answer you have linked indicates, the key here is that the exact meaning of $\Bbb R^2$ (or equivalently $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$) depends in the context that we are working in.

In settings where $\Bbb R$ and/or $\Bbb C$ are the only rings/fields being discussed (typically in problems of an area whose name includes the word "analysis"), $\Bbb R^2$ typically refers to the abelian group/vector space over the set $\Bbb R^2$.  In other words, no multiplication between elements is defined or considered.

However, in settings where $\Bbb R$ and/or $\Bbb C$ are considered to be one ring among many (typically in problems of an area whose name includes the word "algebra(ic)"), $\Bbb R^2$ refers to the multiplication associated with the product $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ of rings. That is, $\Bbb R^2$ a ring with multiplication defined by $(a,b)\cdot(c,d) = (ac,bd)$.

The symbol $\Bbb R^2$ is never used to refer to $\Bbb R^2$ with the complex-number multiplication $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = (ac - bd,ad + bc)$, except perhaps for pedagogical reasons. Where the set $\Bbb R^2$ is given this multiplication rule, the symbol $\Bbb C$ is used instead.

Comment: So in conclusion *I* have to define any sort of algebraic structure on it, and $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not have structure by itself(but in different contexts it can be interpreted to have different structures).

Comment: @ICanKindOfCode I would say that the following is perhaps more accurate: in most contexts, $\Bbb R^2$ does not come with any sort of multiplicative structure, but it almost always comes with the usual notion of $+$. The only time where $\Bbb R^2$ does have a multiplicative structure that does not explicitly need to be explained is when we are already discussing the product $R \times S$ of rings (which comes with a multiplication over $R \times S$), and $\Bbb R^2$ arises as one such product.

Answer (score 3):

You have that from the same abelian group (in this case $\mathbb{R}^2$) you can obtain different non-isomorphic rings if you consider it with different multiplications.
In this case $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are both rings but with different multiplications.

In the first case, as *Randall* commented, you have that the group you are considering became a field. In the second case it's not a field (for example $(1,0)$ doesn't admit any inverse).

So, even if the abelian group is the same, you can construct different rings on it.

Comment: Wait, so when i say "$\mathbb{R}^2$", are we talking about the abelian group or the ring? can it mean both?

Comment: If you use the term $\mathbb{R}^2$, you will be commonly understood to be referring to an abelian group, or an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Comment: So my doubt in this was just a problem of nomenclature, and the other multiplicative structure I showed(componentwise) can also form a ring from the abelian group $\mathbb{R}^2$, but then $\mathbb{R}^2$ *by itself* is not a ring because we only define an additive structure to it? @rogerl

Comment: It is your job to specify the ring structure, since as this answer points out, it is not unique.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ by itself is not anything other than a set of points. The point is that the symbol is by general agreement used to represent the abelian group. If you wish it to represent something else, then as @Randall has pointed out, you must explicitly specify what.